# How can I place a title on the bottom middle of every photo in my grid gallery?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How can I place a title on the bottom of an image, right in the middle of every photo in my grid gallery, with a thin light-gray background so that it's fully visible no matter what image I use? So far I only managed to put text below but not on the image. Thank you for your time and here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px;
}

.container img {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 12%;
}

.container img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

h2,
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 19px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
  <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="photo">
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need to wrap each image and it's title in a separate div and place *those* in your grid. Then overlay using any of the techniques that can be found on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your images in a `figure` element. Add `figcaption` for the text.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>text text text</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>text text text</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>text text text</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>text text text</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="">
    <figcaption>text text text</figcaption>
  </figure>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i place the text within a box on the bottom of the image?

Comment: Adjust the value of the `bottom` property. Try `-25px` for example.